# Taking subset of multi-index pandas df, unexpected behavior with index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, multi-index

I have data from many repetitions of a particular data stream organized as multi-indexed dataframes (where each repetition is marked as e.g. `['rep1', 'rep2', .., 'repN']`). I often need to take a subset of the larger dataframe in a range of these repetitions (e.g. `df.loc['rep5':'rep50', :]`).

I have not been able to figure out a way to do this, though, without the index of the subsequent subset still retaining the entire list of index values from the larger datarame (i.e. `['rep1', 'rep2', .., 'repN']`).

So, for a simplified example, given the following df:

```
dfs = [pd.DataFrame({'vals': range(3)}) for i in range(3)]
df = pd.concat(dfs, keys=['l1', 'l2', 'l3'])

df

      vals
l1 0     0
   1     1
   2     2
l2 0     0
   1     1
   2     2
l3 0     0
   1     1
   2     2
```

And then taking a subset of it:

```
subset = df.loc['l2':, :]
subset
      vals
l2 0     0
   1     1
   2     2
l3 0     0
   1     1
   2     2
```

Looking at the index of the subset, the original `'l1'` index remains:

```
subset.index
MultiIndex(levels=[['l1', 'l2', 'l3'], [0, 1, 2]],
           labels=[[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

If I reset that index level, however, `'l1'` seems to disappear:

```
subset.reset_index(level=0)
    level_0 vals
0   l2  0
1   l2  1
2   l2  2
0   l3  0
1   l3  1
2   l3  2
```

And then I can put `'level_0'` back in as an index, essentially arriving at what I'm trying to achieve

```
subset.reset_index(level=0).set_index('level_0', append=True).reorder_levels([1, 0]).index
MultiIndex(levels=[['l2', 'l3'], [0, 1, 2]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]],
           names=['level_0', None])
```

However this is obviously a very circuitous route. The other option I suppose is to drop the other rows, but I find `df.drop` to be very unwieldy when trying to do a range of rows for a multi-index df.

This behavior does not occur if the dataframe is not hierarchical. E.g.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': range(5)}, index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

df.index
Index(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], dtype='object')
```

and then taking a subset

```
subset = df.loc[('b', 'c', 'd'),:]
subset.index
Index(['b', 'c', 'd'], dtype='object')
```

It's not clear to me why this is behaving the way that it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What, I think, you need is [pd.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html#pandas-multiindex-remove-unused-levels)

```
subset.index.remove_unused_levels()
```

Output:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['l2', 'l3'], [0, 1, 2]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])
```

Comment: @user3014097 Yes, new in 0.20.0.

Comment: Is this any way to handle this in older versions of pandas?

Comment: Came across this in the pandas bug tracker. I guess one way to deal with it would be `subset.index.get_level_values(level=0).unique()`, at least for my particular use case where I'm trying to iterate over the repetitions.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking,  Good luck, up grade to 0.20.2 if you can.

Comment: @user3014097 please consider up voting this answer as well.  Thx